# Spring Validator Errors ObjectError

Tags: spring, validation

If I have an `objectError` (of class `ObjectError`), 
now when I do `**messageResource.getMessage(objectError,Locale.US);**`

How can I get exactly which partucular code(out of all the codes in  codes list in `objectError`) got resolved by the messageSource

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Message codes for your [`ObjectError`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/ObjectError.html) instances are resolved by an implementation of the interface [`MessageCodesResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/MessageCodesResolver.html). The default implementation shipping with the Spring framework is called [`DefaultMessageCodesResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html) and its strategy for generating message codes is well documented in the JavaDocs.

The resulting message codes will be resolved in the given order starting with the most precise message code. If you want to know which one was resolved, you would need to resolve the error codes with the help of the `DefaultMessageCodesResolver` from your `ObjectError` and try to resolve the message until you successfully evaluate a given message code to a message.